# $\tau(n) = 1992$ and $\phi(n) \mid n$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the number of positive integers $n$ such that $\tau(n) = 1992$ and $\phi(n) \mid n$ where $\tau(a)$ is the number of different positive divisors of $a$ and $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.

I first found the prime factorization of $1992 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 83$ and so $n$ can have at most $5$ factors. How do we use the fact that $\phi(n) \mid n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to show $\varphi(n)|n$ if and only if $n=2^a3^b$ with $a>0$ or $n=1$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135756/how-do-you-find-all-n-such-that-phinn)).

Knowing this we have $(a+1)(b+1)=1992$, notice that $(a+1)$ can be any divisor of $1992$ except $1$. So there are $\tau(1992)-1=15$ solutions.

Comment: I got that $a+1\neq 1$ but why can't $a+1=2/1992$ can you please explain

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry about that. It should be ok now.

Comment: What is the maximum solution?

Comment: $2^{1991}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @CarryonSmiling How did you determine that?

Comment: I noticed $2^8>3^5$

Comment: Also, technically $\phi(n) \mid n$ when $n = 1$, too.

Comment: Is the answer not satisfactory ?

Comment: I was just saying that you should also mention that $\phi(n) \mid n$ when $n = 1$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for noticing that :)