# A note on conjecture that all the Mersenne numbers are square-free

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

Today, I am posting an approach that seems too elementary to validate. The approach is developed by me while reading the 1967 work of L. Warren and H. Bray. In their article, "*[On the square-freeness of Fermat and Mersenne numbers](https://msp.org/pjm/1967/22-3/pjm-v22-n3-p15-p.pdf)*", they have established interesting congruence relations for the primes whose square divides these Fermat and Mersenne numbers.

However, in the first place, I felt, I must give my take on the problem of square-freeness of Mersenne Numbers. Here, in this script, I've discussed my approach to the problem.

**To prove:** Every number $M_p = 2^p -1$ is square-free for all primes $p$.

**Proof:**

We assume that $M_p$ is not square-free, to proceed with the method of contradiction.
This implies that,

$$M_p = (8c+1) (4k \pm 1)$$

Here, $(8c+1)$ comes from the fact, that odd-square is of form $8c+1$. And the other factor, $4k \pm 1$ is simply assumed because every odd number can be represented in this form.

**Case 1:** $2^p -1 = (8c+1)(4k+1)$

$2^p -1 = 32ck + 8c + 4k + 1$

$2^p = 32ck + 8c + 4k + 2$

$2^{p-1} = 16ck + 4c + 2k + 1$

$2^{p-1} = 2q + 1$

Here, $q = 8ck + 2c + k$. However, no even number is never equivalent to an odd number. Hence, a contradiction.

**Case 2:** $2^p -1 = (8c+1)(4k-1)$

$2^p-1 = 32ck - 8c + 4k -1$

$2^p = 32ck - 8c + 4k$

$2^{p-2} = 8ck - 2c + k$

Now, if we compute, Euler totient function $\phi$ of above equation, we've,

$2^{p-3} = \phi(8ck- 2c + k)$.

But, $2^{p-2} = 2^{p-3}*2 = 8ck -2c + k$. Hence, $2^{p-3} = 4ck - c + \frac{k}{2}$. Now, notice that left hand side of last equation is an integer for all values of $p$ which makes $k = 2r$ for some some integer $r$. Ultimately, we have, $2^{p-3} = 8cr - c + r$.

Now, we let $m = 8cr - c + r$.

Using the last equation and the equation obtained by computing the Euler totient function, we have,

$$\phi(2m) = m$$.

For above to be true, $gcd(2,m) = 1$, which implies that $m$ is an odd number. Recalling, $m = 8cr - c + r = 2^{p-3}$. Hence, a contradiction.

This completes the proof.

The approach seems to be too elementary to me. I will be thankful to the Stack community if they can review this approach and give their valuable insights on the same.

Comment: "For [$\phi(2m)=m$] to be true, $\gcd(2,m)=1$." That claim is false. $\phi(2\cdot 2^r) = 2^r$ for all $r$, and if $r\gt 0$, then $\gcd(2,2^r)\neq 1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If $gcd(p,m) = 1$ then, and only then multiplicative property of totient funciton can be applied to $n = pm$ which makes $\phi(n) = \phi(p) \times \phi(m)$.

Comment: What *is* true is that $\phi(2m)=\phi(m)$ if and only if $m$ is odd: write $m=2^ks$ with $s$ odd. If $k=0$ we get $\phi(2m)=\phi(m)$ from multiplicativity. If $k\gt 0$, we get $\phi(2m) = 2^k\phi(s)=2\phi(m)$.

Comment: Also, I would like to cite the following article on the same. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2223.pdf

Comment: But you don't have $\phi(2m)=\phi(m)$. You have $\phi(2m) = m$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin True sir, let me do the necessary edits. Thank you for rectifying.

Comment: Regarding your case 1, $2^n-1\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ for all $n>1$, and in particular this holds for any prime exponent. So case 1 never occurs.

Comment: It's not a typo. It's the fundamental flaw in your argument. The conclusion that $\phi(2m)=m$ is correct. The conclusion that $m$ is odd does not follow. In fact, the only numbers for which $\phi(n)$ divides $n$ are $n=1$ and those of the form $2^a3^b$ with $a\gt 0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135788/742)). Of those, the only ones with the equality you want are the powers of $2$. So the only conclusion you can draw about $m$ is that $m$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes sir, it was my bad. I was trying to do something and end up with something silly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin However sir, if we look at $\phi(8ck - 2c + k) = 2^{p-3}$, and look for number of solutions to the $\phi(n) = 2^j$. The number of solutions is either $j+2$ or $32$ depending on the primality of Fermat Number $F_{33}$. I would be thankful if you can guide me, on whether this fact can be used to prove the square-freeness of Mersenne Numbers?

Comment: Only a partial result is known : If $p$ is a prime and $q$ a prime with $q^2\mid 2^p-1$ , then $q$ is a Wieferich prime different from the two known Wieferich primes. This makes it likely that $2^p-1$ with prime $p$ is always squarefree, but the conjecture is still open.